# AJAX JSONP: parsing response causes error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, jsonp

Whenever i call my service I get parse error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
{"Catagory":"Sample language","Name":"Sample Book","Price":50}
-----------↑
```

Here is my code for client side:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btSubmit').click(function () {
      $.ajax({ 
        type:"GET",
        url: url, // Location of the service
        contentType: "application/json;charset-uf8", // content type sent to server
        dataType: "jsonp", //Expected data format from server
        success: function (msg) {
          alert(msg);
          //Implement get data from service as you wish
        },
        error: function (err) {
          alert(err);
          // When Service call fails
        }
      });     
    });
  });
</script>
```

And code for server side..i am using wcf service

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]
public interface IBooks
{
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat =            WebMessageFormat.Json,RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]      
BookDetails ShowBookDetails(string sBookID);

[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
BookDetails JsonData(string Id);
}
```

Comment: Add the full error message

Comment: Syntax error:missing;before statement

Comment: actually i used Jsnop in client side,and i think the response by server is given in json..thats y m getting this error..but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Since you control api can implement CORS instead of using jsonp. Using either approach assumes you are working cross domain between client page and api

Comment: can you please tell me..how to implement that@charlietfl

Comment: Is your ajax request url lies in the same domain name and port number?

Comment: no...different domain...thats why i used jsonp...but it is giving me parse error

Comment: Removed link to picture, formatted code.

Comment: @tiya what is the answer?